# in bash, bash remove punctuation between pattern matches?

Tags: bash

I am struggling with a conversion of a data file to csv when there is punctuation in the title field.

I have a bash script that obtains the file and processes it, and it almost works.  What gets me is when there are commas in a free text title field, which then create extra fields.

I have tried some sed examples to replace between patterns but I have not gotten any of them to work.  What I want to do is work between two patterns and replace commas with either nothing or perhaps a semicolon.

Taking this string:

```
name:A100040,title:Oatmeal is better with raisins, dates, and sugar,current_balance:50000,
```

Replacing with this:

```
name:A100040,title:Oatmeal is better with raisins dates and sugar,current_balance:50000,
```

I should probably use "title:" and ",current_" to denote the start and end of the block where I want to make the change to avoid situations like this:

```
name:A100040,title:Re-title current periodicals, recent books,current_balance:50000,
```

So far I have not gotten the substitution to match.  In this case I am using !! to make the change obvious:

```
teststring="name:A100040,title:Oatmeal is better with raisins, dates, and sugar,current_balance:50000,"

echo $teststring |sed '/title:/,/current_/s/,/!!/g'
name:A100040!!title:Oatmeal is better with raisins!! dates!! and sugar!!current_balance:50000!!
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that the addresses you specify before the 's' operator are used to choose which *lines* to operate on, not to choose an arbitrary block of text.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way which could undoubtedly be refined:

```
perl -ple 'm/(.*?)(title:.*?)(current_balance:.*)/; $save = $part = $2; $part =~ s/,/!!/g;  s/$save/$part/'
```

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  I understand there being smarter ways to work with CSV files but I really needed to move forward.

Comment: @user1463598: Your comment seems to be more applicable to William Pursell's answer. If you find one of the answers useful or helpful, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

First, using `sed` or `awk` to parse CSV is almost always the wrong thing to do, because they do not allow field delimiters to be quoted.  That said, it seems like a better approach would be to quote the fields so that your output would be:

```
name:"A100040",title:"Oatmeal ... , dates, and sugar",current_balance:50000
```

Using `sed` you can try: (this is fragile)

```
sed 's/:\([^:]*\),\([^,:]*\)/:"\1",\2/g'
```

If you insist on trying to parse the csv with "standard" tools and you consider `perl` to be standard, you could try:

```
perl -pe '1 while s/,([^,:]*),/ $1,/g'
```